# Using COUNT and GROUP BY in query with joins limiting results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a count of a specific field form one table while also retrieving data from other tables. The query is running successfully, however I am getting limited results.

Here are my tables:

**students** - studentID, fname, lname, yearLevel, rollClass

**classes** - classID, classCode, subjectID

**subjects** - subjectID, subjectName

**studentclasses** - studentClassID, studentID, classID

When I run this query, I get a full list of student classes, from all roll classes (around 100,000 entries with 77 roll classes). The roll class has the format: YearlevelLetter (i.e. 10A, 11S).

```
SELECT 
    s.EQ_ID, s.rollClass, c.classCode, su.subjectName
FROM 
    students AS s INNER JOIN 
    (
        studentclasses AS sc INNER JOIN 
        (
            classes AS c  INNER JOIN subjects AS su
            ON c.subjectID = su.subjectID
        ) ON sc.classID = c.classID
    ) ON s.studentID = sc.studentID
```

However, I am wanting to count how many students are in each roll class, in each subject, so I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(s.EQ_ID), s.rollClass, su.subjectName
FROM 
    students AS s INNER JOIN 
    (
        studentclasses AS sc INNER JOIN 
        (
            classes AS c  INNER JOIN subjects AS su 
            ON c.subjectID = su.subjectID
        ) ON sc.classID = c.classID
    ) ON s.EQ_ID = sc.EQ_ID
GROUP BY s.rollClass, su.subjectName
```

This query gives me results from only the first 4 roll classes (the first 4 it comes across), only , the rest are not present.

Am I missing something, why would I be getting limited results when I know that there is more data in the DB?

I am entering the query directly into the SQL part of PHPMyadmin. All tables are using MyASAM.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's `EQ_ID` field? None of your tables have that field.

Comment: Assuming that EQ_ID is the studentID, then the 2 queries are the same (save the group by clause), therefore the 2nd query should return all the rollClass - subjectName pairs that the 1st query returns. If it does not do that, then I would run the query in a different GUI, not phpmyadmin.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the EQ_ID field is student ID (I was trying to clean up my actual column names to make it easier to read, however I missed the second query).

Comment: Great. Then try to run the quey in a different GUI (or command line client) to eliminate phpmyadmin bugs.

Comment: Thanks Shadow, it seems to be a PHPMyadmin error. When I copied the data to a XAMPP server with a newer version of PHPMyadmin, the query worked correctly.

Comment: Honestly, I avoid using phpmyadmin for development purposes. It is too buggy. For administering remote databases it is fine. I would delete this question because there is no problem with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, and thanks to Shadow for providing the answer. This was caused by an issue with PHPMyadmin. When I copied the data to another server with a newer version of PHPMyadmin, the query showed all results.

Comment: I would delete this question. It does not add much value to the site, since there was no issue with the query.

Answer (score 0):

If it's phpMyAdmin weirdness, you could try adding and see what happens:

```
ORDER BY s.rollClass, su.subjectName
```

You shouldn't need it, but from your comment that it's taking the first 4 values of `rollClass` it sees...

Comment: This was giving the same result. But it was a PHPMyadmin error.

Answer (score -1):

Your first query is selecting across 4 columns:

```
SELECT s.EQ_ID, s.rollClass, c.classCode, su.subjectName
```

Your second query is selecting across only three of those columns, and then grouping by two:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.EQ_ID), s.rollClass, su.subjectName
```

This means that it is aggregating across different values for `c.classCode`.  Perhaps try this to aggregate the results from your first query:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.EQ_ID), s.rollClass, c.classCode, su.subjectName
FROM students AS s INNER JOIN (studentclasses AS sc INNER JOIN (classes AS c  INNER JOIN subjects AS su ON c.subjectID = su.subjectID) ON sc.classID = c.classID) ON s.EQ_ID = sc.EQ_ID
GROUP BY s.rollClass, c.classCode, su.subjectName
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the same result (just with the classCode included). I still have the limited results. I don't actually need the classCode, I just included it in my first query to help with debugging it.

Comment: That the 1st query has another field in the select list does not change how many rollClass values are displayed.

Comment: I read the question as the query having returned 4 rows.  On that assumption, if (rollClass, classCode) is not unique, then the original query would return less rows.